# Unable to change ng-href onClick event

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-href

I have a footer with a `button` in my `angular` app. The button has an `ng-href` attribute which should change during the `ng-click` event to affect the routing mechanism. For some reason I cant make this work. The ultimate goal is to append numbers, 1 to five each button click.

The footer is a `component`:

```
app.component('footerx', {
    bindings: {

    },
    templateUrl: 'views/footer.html',
    controller: function () {
        this.buttonText = "Next";
        var self = this;
        var i = 1;
        this.changeHref= function () {
            self.questionIndex=i;
            i++;
        }
    }
});
```

Footer HTML:

```
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$ctrl.changeHref()" ng-href="#/quiz/{{questionIndex}}" id="btn">{{$ctrl.buttonText}}</a>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Routing JS part:

```
...
        .when("/quiz/:index", {
            templateUrl: "views/questionPage.html",
            controller: "questionController"
        })
...
```

EDIT:
Right now the `url` does not fully change. This means it does not have the `questionIndex`. It looks like this:

```
http://localhost/myApp/#/quiz/
```

Comment: Can you please go into more detail on your attempts to debug? Is there a before and after url you see? Is `questionINdex` changing?

Comment: The URL only changes to `http://localhost/myApp/#/quiz/` inseat of `http://localhost/myApp/#/quiz/1` . Not much other debug data is present.

Comment: Oh, use `$scope` not `self`. `$scope` has access to the templating interpolation

Comment: But I'm using this inside of an angular `component`, you suppose to use `this`, no?

Comment: I haven't done much work with components, but you should be able to inject $scope into the controller and it should inherit from the parent.

Comment: Yes it certainly does work with $scope. Didnt think this is the right way to go. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `"#/quiz/{{$ctrl.questionIndex}}`

```
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- REMOVE
        <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$ctrl.changeHref()" 
                  ng-href="#/quiz/{{questionIndex}}" id="btn"> 
           {{$ctrl.buttonText}}
        </a>
        -->
        <!--ADD -->
        <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$ctrl.changeHref()" 
                  ng-href="#/quiz/{{$ctrl.questionIndex}}" id="btn"> 
           {{$ctrl.buttonText}}
       </a>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks! can't believe i didnt notice the missing `$ctrl`.